# Solve multiple integral $\int_{-2}^{1} \int_{-2}^{1} \int_{-2}^{1} \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx \,dy \,dz$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

I found this integral in a book. I thought it was easy to solve it, but I've not been able to do it. I tried to use spherical coordinates, however, I'm not sure what the limits are in such coordinates. Any suggestion?

$$\int_{-2}^{1} \int_{-2}^{1} \int_{-2}^{1} \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx \,dy \,dz$$

Answer (score 7):

Per the symmetry
$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx \,dy \,dz\\
=\frac13 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dx\, dy \,dz =\frac83$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I've edited my post with the correct problem.

Comment: @AlexisGalois: Editing a question after getting an answer is definitely not encouraged here. Not even saying that your "correction" doesn't change much - where are your own attempts?